# Why isn't std::find() using my operator==?

Tags: c++, stl

In the following snippet of code, I've overloaded the `operator==` to compare my pair type with string.  But for some reason, the compiler isn't finding my operator as a match for the find function.  Why not?

***Edit:*** Thanks for all the suggestions for alternatives, but I'd still like to understand *why*.  The code looks like it should work; I'd like to know why it doesn't.

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::pair<std::string, int> RegPair;
typedef std::vector<RegPair> RegPairSeq;

bool operator== (const RegPair& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
    return lhs.first == rhs;
}

int main()
{
    RegPairSeq sequence;
    std::string foo("foo");
    // stuff that's not important
    std::find(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), foo);
    // g++: error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first. __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>*, _Container = std::vector<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > >]() == __val'
    // clang++: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, int>' and 'std::basic_string<char> const')
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::map`?

Comment: @sbi: This is a simple example, based on something found in a larger code base.  There are other constraints that make use want to use the vector of pairs.

Comment: @dave: I know there are reasons for doing this (in fact, I have done this, too, in the past), but considering the type of questions we get here sometimes, I thought it best to at least ask.

Comment: Rather than typedef create your own class: `class RegPair: public std::pair<std::string, int> {};` Since your class is now in the global namespace it will not find your version of the operator==. The reason your current one fails is that typedef is not really a typedef it is a type alias (ie another name for a type). Thus it does not help in ADL.

Comment: @dave, @sbi : You may be interested in [`boost::container::flat_map<>`](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/move/libs/container/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html) from the recently-officially-accepted [Boost.Containers](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/move/libs/container/doc/html/index.html) library. I believe the library is expected to be included in the official Boost distribution starting in 1.49.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that `std::find` is a function template and it uses argument-dependent lookup (ADL) to find the right `operator==` to use.

Both of the arguments are in the `std` namespace (`std::pair<std::string, int>` and `std::string`), so ADL starts by looking in the `std` namespace.  There it finds some `operator==` (which one, it doesn't matter; there are lots in the Standard Library and if you've included `<string>`, at least the one that compares two `std::basic_string<T>` objects could be found).

Because an `operator==` overload is found in the `std` namespace, ADL stops searching enclosing scopes.  Your overload, which is located in the global namespace, is never found.  Name lookup occurs before overload resolution; it doesn't matter during name lookup whether the arguments match.

Comment: "Because an `operator==` overload is found in the `std` namespace, ADL stops searching..." This is actually inaccurate. There's no "because" here. `std` is the only namespace nominated for ADL. so ADL looks there and nowhere else. It does not matter whether an existing overload of `operator==` is found in `std` or not. ADL will not look outside of `std` in either case.

Answer (score 17):

The cleanest solution is to make a predicate and use `find_if`:

```
struct StringFinder
{
  StringFinder(const std::string & st) : s(st) { }
  const std::string s;
  bool operator()(const RegPair& lhs) const { return lhs.first == s; }
}

std::find_if(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), StringFinder(foo));
```

If you have C++11 you can use a lambda instead.

Comment: Beat my by 54secs! `+1` from me.

Comment: Yes - this is what we finally did, and lambdas would have made it awesome.  But I'm still curious why `std::find` isn't finding my `operator==`.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have any custom types in your setup. If you had, say, `RegPair = std::pair<std::string, Foo>`, then it'd be OK. You can only overload if at least one of the types is custom.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is, unfortunately, misleading.

Overload resolution for operator `==` used inside `std::find` function template is performed by both regular lookup and argument-dependent lookup (ADL)

1. Regular lookup is performed in accordance with usual rules of unqualified name lookup. It is looked up from the definition of `std::find` in standard library. Obviously, the above user-provided declaration of `operator ==` is not visible from there.
2. ADL is a different story. Theoretically ADL can see names defined later, e.g. names visible from the point of `std::find` invocation inside `main`. However, ADL does not just see everything. ADL is restricted to searching only inside so called [*associated namespaces*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2). These namespaces are brought into the consideration by types of arguments used in the invocation of operator `==` in accordance to the rules of [6.4.2/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2).

   In this example types of both arguments of `==` belong to namespace `std`. One template argument of `std:pair<>` is also from `std`. Another is of fundamental type `int`, which has [no associated namespace](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2.1). Therefore `std` is the only associated namespace in this case. ADL looks in `std` and only in `std`. The above user-provided declaration of `operator ==` is not found, since it resides in global namespace.

   It is incorrect to say that ADL stops looking after finding some "other" definitions of `operator ==` inside `std`. ADL does not work in "inside-out" fashion as other forms of lookup often do. ADL searches in associated namespaces and that's it. Regardless of whether any other forms of `operator ==` were found in `std` or not, ADL does not attempt to continue its search in global namespace. This is the incorrect/misleading part of the accepted answer.

Here's a more compact example that illustrates the same issue

```
namespace N
{
  struct S {};
}

template<typename T> void foo(T a) 
{
  bar(a);
}

void bar(N::S s) {}

int main()
{
  N::S a;
  foo(a);
}
```

Ordinary lookup fails since there's no `bar` declared above `foo`. Seeing that `bar` is called with an argument of `N::S` type, ADL will look for `bar` in associated namespace `N`. There's no `bar` in `N` either. The code is ill-formed. Note that absense of `bar` in `N` does not make ADL to expand its search into the global namespace and find global `bar`.

It is quite easy to inadvertently change the set of associated namespaces used by ADL, which is why such issues often come and go after seemingly innocent and unrelated changes in the code. For example, if we change the declaration of `RegPair` as follows

```
enum E { A, B, C };
typedef std::pair<std::string, E> RegPair;
```

the error will suddenly disappear. After this change global namespace also becomes associated for ADL, along with `std`, which is why ADL finds the user-provided declaration of `operator ==`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Another "correct" solution:

```
struct RegPair : std::pair<std::string, int>
{
    bool operator== (const std::string& rhs) const;
};

bool RegPair::operator== (const std::string& rhs) const
{
    return first == rhs;
}
```

Comment: This solution lacks an explanation of *why* it works. Recall that the question asks *why* it's a problem, not *how* to fix it.